# Where are "System icons" located?

Tags: macos, xcode11

I just downloaded Xcode 11 Beta, started a simple project to see what's new, and saw that in storyboard when you select a button/image in Attributes Inspector in "Image" drop down menu there are new system icons. I want use this icons in my non-Beta Xcode for my project, where are this files located in finder so I can copy them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the symbols here:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreGlyphs.bundle/Assets.car
```

*Edit:*

Apple released a macOS app called SF Symbols where you can view and export those symbols easily: [Apple Design Resources - SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/)

Comment: You can't use them in the way you can use them in Xcode 11. But you could export the symbols you want to use and add them as regular assert to your Xcode 10 project. I've used the [Asset Catalog Tinkerer](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer) App to open this .car file and there are options to export selected symbols.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/#sf-symbols

Please visit here and download al symbols usig dmg